# Azure Webjob TimerTrigger not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

So im trying to use the Timer Trigger in the Azure WebJobs SDK but it dosent appear to be triggering.

This is my Main method

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.UseTimers();

JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

And this is my method

```
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static void GetNextMaint([TimerTrigger("00:00:01", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo info, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine("Getting info from url")
    var info = WebsiteHelper.GetInfoFromWebsite(..website...);
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    db.Info.Add( new Info{ text = info} );
    db.SaveChanges();
    log.WriteLine("Complete, shutting down")
}
```

It works fine if I invoke it manually so there's nothing wrong with the code in the method. I've also tried to use other times, eg `00:01:00`.
I also have another method that runs off a queue which invokes fine. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665763/azure-webjobs-timertrigger-not-triggering

Comment: @Nitin Thanks, I didn't know about the development settings. Still the same problem but it should prove useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `[NoAutomaticTrigger]` attribute.

If you decorate a function with this attribute, the `JobHost` will not index your function to be triggered.

Comment: Oh... that makes sense thanks. I put that there a little while ago when the `JobHost` wasn't seeing my Functions